# как сдедать проверку на равенство значения с ключом объекта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть объект и есть некий массив значений `this.props.id` приходят в компонент

```
"101763": {
    "type": "eng",
    "ok": false
},
"101764": {
    "type": "eng",
    "ok": false
},
"101880": {
    "type": "eng",
    "ok": true
},
```

Как мне сравнить `this.props.id` с каждым ключом объекта? То есть если `this.props.id` = какому-то из ключей `101763`, `101764`, `101880` то нужно написать такую проверку

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, а почему не `myAwesomeObject.hasOwnProperty(this.props.id)`?

Comment: @Grundy, ну да, если ничего дополнительно не надо то так)

Comment: нужно без hasOwnProperty. линтер ругается на него

Comment: вот я вывела this.props.id и this.props.object/ нужно выполнить проверку если id совпадает с одним из ключей  this.props.object.....
https://jsbin.com/wenowisaxe/edit?html,console

Comment: _нужно без hasOwnProperty. линтер ругается на него_ - выкидывай свой линтер. это стандартное средство проверки наличия свойства в объекте.

Comment: @Grundy оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ